# Django - Perform Raw SQL Update/Delete and return row count

Tags: django, mysql

Going off the documentation here: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/

```
>>>cursor = connection.cursor()
>>>cursor.execute("UPDATE bar SET foo = 1 WHERE baz = %s", [self.baz])
>>>print cursor.fetchone()
None
```

Does anyone know how to return the modified row count?

(NOTE: I've played around with the placement/order of transaction.commit_unless_managed() and cursor.fetchone() (also cursor.fetchall()) and it doesn't seem to make a difference)

Thanks!
-Tom

Answer (score 32, accepted):

An UPDATE statement as you've got in your example doesn't return row results, so `fetchone()` will always be empty (or might throw an error).

Use `cursor.rowcount` to get the rows last affected.